# Docker rails app wont talk to postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been trying to setup my rails project on docker along with a postgres database but for some reason my rails project wont connect to the database

I can connect to the database using a database tool like Psequel so that proves that the database is actually running and is good. But for some odd reason my rails app wont connect to the database. This is the error I get

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5435?
 could not connect to server: Address not available
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5435?
```

Following is the docker compose file.

```
version: "3"

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database:
  abc-database:

services:
  testproject:
    networks:
      app:
        aliases:
          - testproject
    image: 34543.aws.testprojectimage:ac877887
    environment: 
      DATABASE_HOST: localhost
      # DATABASE-HOST: abc-db
      DATABASE_USER: test
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: testpass
      DATABASE_NAME: abc
      DATABASE_PORT: 5435
      # DATABASE_URL: postgres://test:testpass@localhost:5435/abc
      LOCAL_TESTS: 1
    ports:
    - 4000:3000/tcp
    depends_on: 
      - "abc-database"

  abc-database:
    container_name: abc-db
    networks:
      app:
        aliases:
          - abc-db
    image: postgres:10.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpass
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_DB: abc
    ports:
       - 5435:5432
    # volumes:
    #   - abc-database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

- I have tried to ensure that the connection object has correct credentials by running `docker exec -it testproject sh` going into the container and doing a manual active record connection and all credentials were correct. But the connection failed with the same above error.
- I also tried to use the database_url in the environment variables and that did not work too.
- I was using a volume for the postgres database but to rule out the possibility of an issue from a postmaster file, i got rid of it so each time i bring up the project a new database is set up. But i continued to get the same error
- I tried to use `abc-db` as the `DATABASE-HOST` and that did not work as well

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the Compose service name of the other container `abc-database` and the standard MySQL port 5432; `ports:` aren't used here (and aren't required).  You can also delete the `container_name:` and `networks:` settings to simplify things a little more.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose is creating domain aliases for each service described in `docker-compose` file so host name for database connection must be the same as a db service name, in your case `abc-database`
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I was able to get it working. The problem was in the port. I initially had set the external to internal mappings of the port but i was good to just use 5432. I also removed all unwanted lines from there. This is what worked for me.

```
version: "3"


services:
  test-project:
    image: 87678.image-aws.com/78677777678
    environment: 
      SWAGGER_HOST: localhost:3000
      SWAGGER_PROTO: http
      MINIO_ENDPOINT: http://127.0.0.1:9000
      DEFAULT_MAILER_SENDER: no-reply@URL_OF_STACK_HERE.com
      PRODUCTION_HOST: project-latest.org-qa.com
      CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION: '91.0.4472.101'
      DATABASE_HOST: abc-database
      DATABASE_USER: test
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: testpass
      DATABASE_NAME: test
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
    ports:
    - 3000:3000/tcp
    depends_on: 
      - "abc-database"

  abc-database:
    image: postgres:10.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpass
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
```

I have removed some unwanted environment variables that were project related. Just to keep project details anonymous.